# Want to convert a menu url to a # using javascript when a mobile device is detected

Tags: javascript, css, ipad

I have a drop down superfish menu in my responsive site and while I have the menu changing to a mobile friendly sidr slide menu for most mobile devices the client would still like to have the orginal dropdown menu showing when a tablet is in landscape orientation.

This obviously creates the usual hover issue with touch devices especially since we have the top li (of a drop down) also providing a href.

My thoughts were that for those particular top level li's we'd add a class on which we could then run some javascript to replace the usual url link with a # when a mobile device is detected.  That would make the top li a touch item instead of a hover link item.

Anyway below is what I have constructed to date and I had though this would work but so far I can't seem to get it to replace the original url with the #

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($){
    var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad|android)/);
    if (agentID) {
        $('#sf-menu.sf-menu li.idevice a').attr('href', '#');
    }
});
</script>
```

I'm guessing I'm missing something really obvious but I've got to that point where I've exhausted my knowledge level - I'm not really a coder, more an enthusiastic tinkerer :).

Below is a snippet of the menu code for reference.

```
<div id="mateen">   
  <ul id="sf-menu" class="sf-menu">  
    <li  class="menu-item"><a href="/Home.htm">Home</a></li>
    <li  class="idevice"><a href="/advantages.htm">Advantages</a>
      <ul>
        <li  ><a href="/advantages.htm">Mateenbar Advantages</a></li>
        <li  ><a href="/superior-performance.htm">Superior Performance</a></li>
        <li  ><a href="/research-and-testing.htm">Research and Testing</a></li>
        <li  ><a href="/FAQ.htm">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
        <li  ><a href="/middle-east.htm">Middle East</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li  class="idevice"><a href="/mateenbar.htm">Products &amp; Specifications</a>
      <ul>
        <li  ><a href="/mateenbar.htm">MateenBar</a></li>
        <li  ><a href="/mateendowel.htm">MateenDowel</a></li>
        <li  ><a href="/mateenbolt.htm">MateenBolt</a></li>
      </ul></li>
    <li  class="idevice"><a href="/corrosion-and-marine.htm">Applications &amp; Projects</a>
      <ul>
        <li  ><a href="/corrosion-and-marine.htm">Corrosion &amp; Marine</a></li>
        <li  ><a href="/roads-and-transportation.htm">Roads &amp; Transportation</a></li>
        <li  ><a href="/tunnelling-and-cutting.htm">Tunnelling &amp; Cutting</a></li>
        <li  ><a href="/electro-magnetic.htm">Electro-magnetic</a></li>
        <li  ><a href="/projects.htm">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li  ><a href="/downloads.htm">Downloads</a></li>
    <li  class="idevice"><a href="/contacts.htm">Contacts</a>
      <ul>
        <li  ><a href="/contacts.htm">Locations</a></li>
        <li  ><a href="/about-pultron.htm">About Pultron</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any advice or help accepted at this point - hope I've provided enough relevant information.

Thanks

Comment: Why show a link that a user can't click on?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the selector. Change the following statement

**$('#sf-menu.sf-menu li.idevice a').attr('href', '#');**

to

**$('#sf-menu > li  > a').attr("href","#")**

For your reference:
https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: Thanks Hari.   it's always the simple things lol.   After posting the question I had an new idea that maybe Superfish had a solution already built in so I went back and checked and after linking their "hoverintent.js" it has seemed to have done exactly what was needed.   I'll give your suggestion ago also as it would be good to know how to do this on menus that aren't superfish .  Thanks

Comment: One more question. Just having a better look at this and I can see that this would I assume arbitrarilly apply the # to all of the first level li's, where as I really need to target only the ones that have the .idevice class as that is how I am deliniating between the dropdown and non-dropdown menu items.   Under that scenario should I specify $('#sf-menu > li.idevice > a').attr("href","#") so as not to target unwanted li's?